# Can indexes on multiple 'range' columns be utilized?

Tags: mysql, optimization, indexing

I've got this index:

```
alter table wx_cbmessage add index main_query (cbm_owner_id,cbm_status,cbm_date,cbm_notification_date);
```

And this query:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ... 
FROM `wx_cbmessage` `msg` FORCE INDEX (main_query) 
    LEFT JOIN wx_user `from` ON cbm_from_user_id=from.login 
WHERE `cbm_owner_id`='username' 
    AND cbm_date <= 1431448013 
    AND (`cbm_notification_date`=0 OR cbm_notification_date <= 1431448013) 
    AND `cbm_status`=1 
ORDER BY `cbm_date` DESC 
LIMIT 25
```

Is there any point having `cbm_notification_date` as part of the index? Can it be utilized?

The first two columns are just exact matches, but I don't know if MySQL can do anything with multiple range searches.

Comment: What does EXPLAIN tell you?

Comment: @Strawberry Not much. It tells me it's using the index, but not which parts of the index. `ref` is actually `NULL` when I use `FORCE INDEX` but says `const,const` if I don't force it, which I think means the first two columns are constant time lookups -- does that mean the other two columns aren't used at all or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please qualify the column names with the table aliases.  Without knowing what column is what table, I have to guess at how to advise.

Two ranges -- Won't be used.

EXPLAIN failing to explain -- Try `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...`.

I recommend this (Since the columns are all in the same table):

```
INDEX(cbm_owner_id, cbm_status, cbm_date)
```

It can be used for 2 constants and a range.  And it can for the `ORDER BY`.
The optimizer has no good way to pick which one to use.

```
(`cbm_notification_date`=0 OR cbm_notification_date <= 1431448013)
```

cannot use an index because of the combination of `OR` and 'range'.  `(x=1 OR x=3)` is equivalent to `(x IN (1,3))`, which is better than a range, although not quite as good as a constant.

Comment: Sorry, `date` *is* `cbm_date`, which is a unix timestamp (BIGINT). What would be the point of having two indexes? I thought MySQL could only use one per table?

Comment: Providing multiple indexes gives the optimizer a choice -- use one index for one set of values; etc.  I will edit my answer to have one index since the field is the same.

Comment: Wow. That `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON` gives a lot more info. I didn't know about that feature. Thank you!